# How to show class="hide" class element by id in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have migrated from bootstrap 2 to bootstrap 3 in my web application,
The *"hide"* class is applied on element, And wanted to override hide class with previous bootstrap class for temp.
even jQuery show() method not work to show "hide" class.

How can i show *"hide"* class using show() method of jQuery?

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" id="test" value="Test"/>

$("#test").show(); // Not work
$(".hide").show(); // Not work
```

I expect show() method of jQuery work for "hide" class of bootstrap 3.

Comment: Did you try `$("#test").removeClass("hide");` ?

Comment: Yes, it works, But i want "hide" class their, bcoz i can't remove that class i had used this in entire project with different reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-show-hide) , hide is deprecated from version 3.0.1. So your best option is to change the class hide to hidden.
If you would still like to use hide class, I think @Akshay's suggestion should work.

**Edit:**
If you can't remove hide class for some reason, you can add an extra class, say unhide, to the element with hide class when you want to show it.
And in the css file you can add code such that whenever hide and unhide come together you show the element.

When you want to hide the element, you can just remove the class using removeClass().

```
$('#test').addClass('unhide'); // when you want to show the element.
$('#test').removeClass('unhide'); // when you want to hide the element.
```

And in css :

```
.hide.unhide { display: block !important; } /* overriding the hide class */
```

Comment: I had used this in entire project with different reasons and conditions, I can't replace all with hidden, How can i override .hide class to .hidden class.

Comment: Please check the above edit and let me know if it fixes the problem or any other concerns are there.